# Meaning of "strips thin but delicate"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "strips thin but very delicate" in the following precisely-quoted passage?

> "My grandson Vin come at weekends and he likes to sun himself in the garden.  He strips thin but very delicate, and a lovely choice of the trunks.  Gold and white satin." — p.57, *Anglo-Saxon Attitudes*, 1956, Angus Wilson.

The quotation is part of Mrs. Salad's explanation to Gerald Middleton about living at the residence of her daughter, Gladys.  Mrs. Salad is Middleton's former char-lady, and is visiting him two days before Christmas, for exchange of gifts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When he strips down to his swimming trunks (takes off all his other clothes), this leaves him looking thin, but very delicate (well-proportioned for a boy, probably). And he wears a lovely choice of trunks (this bit is an [anacoluthon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacoluthon)).

Comment: That agrees with all I surmised, but I'm still left wondering whether "strips thin" may have a particular East-coast-of-England meaning.

Comment: @jwpat7: Well, I don't know, could be. But this fragment is written in an informal, playful style: it looks more like a nonce expression. Perhaps someone else knows more.